# Bootstrap put input box side by side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, position, inputbox

Working on radio bottoms, submit and input box. The goal is to make it look like this:

[image]

This is how far I have came. `Bootply:` http://www.bootply.com/126965

Comment: You should begin reading a little about bootstraps grid-system -> http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid. For a start, you cannot achieve what you want what so ever when you are wrapping every form "element" (label+input) into `col-md-7` + `col-md-2` divs. And it becomes even more impossible when you wrap each "element" into a `form-group`.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of `float:left;` on the `.form-horizontal`.

Then wrap each individual `.form-group` in

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-md-6'>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/126981) - It needs to be tweaked to get it exactly how you want it.

Also sorry about the text indentation, bootply does a horrible job of it and i'm too lazy to fix.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look. I just noticed that it looks awful with mobile/smartphone preview :/ The input box are huge. And submit bottoms are not next to eachother.

Comment: That's when you use `col-sm-*` :) @user3185936

Comment: Hmm! I will try to see if I can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You could checkout inline forms( as described here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline ) or maybe as suggested form-groups and columns described here: MOVED TO FIDDLE

UPDATE: As suggested in comment - plus bonus

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Enter email">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password">
</div>
</form>
```

As such the inline solution doesn't really provide a top notch solution - since it is in one row only.

I made a fiddle for the other example: http://jsfiddle.net/pZCUy/2/

I hope that clears up things a bit.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Oh - I will edit my answer to include the essentials. Thanks for the pointer :-)